# Importing Cadstar/Orcad project into Altium

Tags: altium, orcad, library, script

I have a couple of questions regarding the importing process from Cadstar/Orcad project files to Altium.

First question is regarding the importing process itself. I have managed to import into Altium both the schematic design and library (from a .DSN file) and the PCB design and footprint library (from a .CPA file). However both libraries are not linked together and it seems the only way of linking the schematic library items to the footprint library items is manually.
Is there any way of automating this process?

Another option would be to forget the imported libraries and link the components to our Altium library by using the tool "Update from Libraries...". But it seems that I would also need to go part by part (browsing our library, selecting the correct part, etc, etc).
Is there anyway of automating this process, taking into account that the imported schematic parts share several parameters with the parts present in our library?

Second question is regarding the automation of the importing process. I have a bunch of boards that have been designed in Orcad and that will need to be imported into Altium. Is there any way of scripting this whole process?

I'm not asking of course for the full scripts that do these tasks, just for a bit of help in finding the references and a starting point.